# How to get the map zoom action on Ti.map

Tags: google-maps, titanium

There are articles about ti.map.

[Map](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map/blob/master/apidoc/Map.yml)

[View](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map/blob/master/apidoc/View.yml)

I found some entry about zoom.

However I couldn't figure out how to get the map zoom level,
when user pinch the maps on devices.

I tried like this but in vain.

```
    var mapView = Map.createView({
        mapType:Map.NORMAL_TYPE,
        userLocation:true,
        region: {latitude:35.699058, longitude:139.326099,    
        latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
        animate:false,regionFit:true,
        userLocation:true,
    });

    mapView.addEventListener('pinch', function(evt) {
        Ti.API.info("pinch " + evt);
    //This is not fired.
    });

    mapView.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        Ti.API.info("Clicked " + evt.clicksource + " on " + evt.latitude + "," + evt.longitude);
    // This is fired.
    });
```

---

Thanks to @Fokke Zandbergen's help

I solve the problem.

```
    mapView.addEventListener('regionChanged',function(evt){
        Ti.API.info('regionchanged delta lati,longi ' + evt.latitudeDelta + "," + evt.longitudeDelta);
        if (evt.latitudeDelta > 0.020){
        //  do something.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve your goal by listening to the [regionchanged](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.View-event-regionchanged) event of the view. You'll get the region displayed, but there's zoom level. Depending on what you need it for you'll have to use the region to calculate that yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I can make it.